# The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available - web3.py

Tags: addresses, web3.py

I am trying to send data to the contract, but I am getting the following error:
**The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available**

This is the code:

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9fe6f0a016494dfeb4cecd7d1c98431a"))

from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

print(web3.eth.blockNumber)

x = web3.isAddress('0xacb0ceacb13e786644f0ab21aa044032ae925874')
print(x)

abi = '''
   ...
      '''

address = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xacb0ceacb13e786644f0ab21aa044032ae925874')

lucas = '0x690809206b73994282910F1740a729a89aF4beCa'

myContract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
key = myContract.functions.storeData([1,4]).transact({'from' : lucas})

print(key)

addedData = myContract.functions.getData(key).call()
print(addedData)
```

The above code can connect to the network rinkeby normally, but cannot perform the transaction. The **storeData** method takes an array and returns an uint which is **key** and is working normally in Remix.

I'm using Metamask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key = myContract.functions.storeData([1,4]).buildTransaction({'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)})

signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(key, private_key='...')

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```