# What is the equivalent of "buildTransaction" of web3Py in web3JS?

Tags: web3js, transactions, web3j, signature

I'm using Node to interact with my smart contract. I understand that I need to first sign my transaction before sending it.

In one of the [StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77637/the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available-web3-py) answers I see that it can be done using buildTransaction method.

How can I do the same implementation in web3JS?

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha!

```
//library
var Web3 = require('web3')
var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
    
//infura config
const rpcURL = "infura url"
var web3 = new Web3(rpcURL);

const contractCall = () => {
    const account = <address>
    const privateKey = <privateKey>
    const contractAddress = <contractAddress>
    const contractABI = <abi>

    //init contract
    var contract = new Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);

    //vote2 function ABI
    const myData = contract.methods.<define your method here>.encodeABI();
    console.log(myData)

    // transaction count
    const transactionCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
    console.log(transactionCount);

    // Transaction Object
    const txObject = {
        nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(transactionCount),
        to:       contractAddress,
        value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
        data: myData  
    }

    // sign
    const tx = new Tx.Transaction(txObject, {chain:'goerli', hardfork: 'petersburg'});
    tx.sign(privateKey);

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

    // Broadcast the transaction
    const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw);
    console.log(transaction);
}
contractCall();
```